# Why sequelize query return one item but raw SQL returns 2 items?

Tags: sequelize.js

Here is a query in sequelize (6.3.5) with model `Artwork` joining `Artimage`:

```
    const { Artwork, validateArtwork} = require('../models/artwork');
    const { Artimage, validateArtimage} = require('../models/artimage');
    artworks = await Artwork.findAll({
            where : { 
                id: {[Op.gt]:last_artwork_id},
            },
            include: [{
                model:Artimage,
                attributes:['width', 'height', ['name', 'img_name'], 'path', 'size_kb', ['label', 'img_label'], ['fileName', 'img_fileName']],
                
            }],
            attributes:{excludes:['fort_token']},
            order:[['id', 'DESC']]
        });
```

Here when `last_artwork_id` is 7, `artwork#8` shall be picked with its 2 images in `artimage`. However `artworks.length` is `1` instead of `2`. But when the raw SQL code is executed, it returns 2 entries as there are 2 images for `artwork#8`. Here is the raw SQL from the code above:

```
 SELECT "artwork"."id", "artwork"."name", "artwork"."auther", "artwork"."category", "artwork"."wt_g", "artwork"."production_year", "artwork"."dimension", 
 "artwork"."uploader_id", "artwork"."description", "artwork"."note", "artwork"."tag", "artwork"."deleted", "artwork"."status", "artwork"."artwork_data", 
 "artwork"."last_updated_by_id", "artwork"."fort_token", "artwork"."createdAt", "artwork"."updatedAt", "artimages"."id" AS "artimages.id", 
 "artimages"."width" AS "artimages.width", "artimages"."height" AS "artimages.height", "artimages"."name" AS "artimages.img_name", "artimages"."path" AS "artimages.path", 
 "artimages"."size_kb" AS "artimages.size_kb", "artimages"."label" AS "artimages.img_label", "artimages"."fileName" AS "artimages.img_fileName" FROM 
 "artworks" AS "artwork" LEFT OUTER JOIN "artimages" AS "artimages" ON "artwork"."id" = "artimages"."artwork_id" WHERE "artwork"."id" > 7 ORDER BY "artwork"."id" DESC
```

Why `artworks.length` is 1 item with `sequelizejs` instead of 2 items (correct)?

Answer (score 0):

`sequelizejs` returns joined `artimage` in an array object with key of table name  `artimages` : `artworks.artimages[0] & artworks.artimages[1]`